# How can I use field values in an expression on a report?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a report with two fields: KWH1 and KWH2.  I'd like to add two more fields to my report that derive their value from the previous fields.  For instance:

```
VAL1 = ([KWH1] * .1105) + ([KWH2] * .288)
VAL2 = ([KWH1] + [KWH2]) * .1435
```

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.  I tried entering the above formulas directly into a cell in the report designer, but it did not work.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the expressions to:

```
=(ReportItems!KWH1.Value * .1105) + (ReportItems!KWH2.Value * .288)
```

and

```
=(ReportItems!KWH1.Value + ReportItems!KWH2.Value) * .1435
```